# Verb endings with complex nouns

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses

Which is correct:

> One of the clearest analogies which helps us understand ...

or

> One of the clearest analogies which help us understand ...

I think it's the first one because 'One of ...' is the subject and it's in the singular form, but it doesn't sound right.  Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["1 out of 100 chickens is" or "1 out of 100 chickens are"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42176/1-out-of-100-chickens-is-or-1-out-of-100-chickens-are)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you should ask yourself here is whether all the analogies in question help us understand what the sentence goes on to describe or only one of them is true in this statement.

With that said, consider this:

**Situation A:** There are 5 people standing in front of you. **Only 1 of them** is a thief. You go on to say:

> One of these people, who is a thief, ...

**Situation B:** There are 5 people standing in front of you and in this scenario, **all of them** are thieves. You would say:

> One of these people who are thieves ...

In situation A, with the *who* part you describe a certain single person, whereas in situation B you use it to describe the whole group you can pick from.

The same goes for **your scenario**.

If of all the analogies you can present only 1 helps you to understand what you want to say, you will use:

> One of the analogies which helps us understand ...

If all the analogies you're presenting help you understand what you want to say, but for whatever reason you're picking only one to describe the situation, you'll say:

> One of the analogies which help us understand ...

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was the case. It basically boils down to which noun is the main object of the sentence and what its grammatical number is. Thanks

Comment: I'm thinking of something and probably will edit my answer in a few  minutes.

Comment: Nah sorry, I was trying to describe the problem of proper/improper use of defining and non-defining relative clauses, but my head almost exploded. I'd need 2 more hours to think this through and I don't think you want to make an inception out of this. Looks like you understand the basic idea and that should be enough for you to make the distinction you need to make.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma before where in "One of the analogies, which helps us understand...". AFAIU this is a non-restricting close and therefore should be separated with a comma . No?

Answer (score 0):

Those are adjectival phrases as they contribute more information to the preceding nouns.

A complex noun is a phrase situated directly after a transitive verb or, in other cases, the subject of a sentence.