# Verb when citing statistics ex. "one in nine Americans (work or works) in sales"

Tags: word-choice

When I read the following sentence:

> According to the U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics, one in nine Americans **works** in sales.

I believe *work* sounds better than *works*.

Experts and wordsmiths, please advise!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['1 out of 100 chickens is' or '1 out of 100 chickens are'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42176/1-out-of-100-chickens-is-or-1-out-of-100-chickens-are/42202#42202)

Comment: And how about 1.75 in 10 Americans? You'll notice the denominator changes to avoid fractions and plurals, thus making the singular a clear choice. Rather than saying 2 in 10 one would typically say 1 in 5. But there are no "rules" here that are not routinely broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old argument. A case can be made for either.

1. One in nine Americans works in sales.

One (in nine Americans) works in sales.

One works in sales.

2. One in nine Americans work in sales.

1/9(320,000,000 )  Americans work in sales.

Thirty-five and a half thousand Americans work in sales.

---

You choose!

Comment: Cheers, chasly!

Comment: Not for his math.